# Does kendo.data.dataSource store the old value somewhere?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

Lets say that you have a kendo.data.DataSource.
and you modify a row.
and the row has become dirty.
and now you want to compare if a specific column was changed before you save.

Does kendo.data.DataSource store the old value locally somewhere?

I suspect it does since it seems that you can call .cancelChanges() and .cancelRow() however i cant seem to find it.

I also suspect that you are not supposed to use it.

Comment: Are you connecting the datasource to a widget like the grid control?  If so, there are events in the widget that let you listen for changes.

Comment: yes i know however i was thinking i could avoid listening to change events if the old value is already stored somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that you are not suppose to use this, but it is located in the Data Source.

The currently displayed data/dirty data to be submitted is stored in `dataSource._data`
The last saved value/non-dirty data is stored in `dataSource._pristineData`

The dirty flag is also stored in _data.

---

In general you don't want to be messing with any variable that begins with the `_`.
You can alternatively save out the current data with the get/set function kendo provides. The `dataSource.data()` function. Update it with the same function `dataSource.data(myNewData)`

Comment: ah. i did notice the _pristineData before, however when i looked, it seemed to contain the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally Kendo will provide such feature. However, the next clean solution I found was by playing with the onfocus and onblure events as following:
onfocus: you store original value
onblure: you do the logic and put back original if needed.

Best of luck and I hope I helped someone :) If so then cheers my friend :)